# "In the air" gesture recognition on iOS devices

Tags: ios, camera, gesture-recognition

I have a completely theoretical question: is there some open-source (or maybe not) project about "i the air" gestures recognition in iOS devices? For example is there some way to recognize the movements that the user does in the air in front of the screen (like scroll or pinch)? I think that it's quite hard to do just with the front camera of iPhone, iPod and iPad  but I want to hear your ideas.

Comment: Maybe take a look at OpenCV...

Comment: I agree with @Macmade. You need to look at OpenCV. If the camera is stable, and there isn't too much background noise, it may be easier than you think.